# Dotnet CSV Helper Unable to Parse file

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

I'm trying to parse a csv file to a list of item of a a given class. I'm pretty new to dotnet world. I'm using .NET (2.2.402)
This is the code for my class

```
public class ItemResource
{ 
    public string Msisdn { get; set; }
    public float Amount { get; set; }
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tells wether or not the customer will receive a notification
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    public int Notify { get; set; }
}
```

This is the section of the code where I try to parse the file

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("path-to-file.csv");

var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader);

//csvReader.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";
//csvReader.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;
var records = csvReader.GetRecords<ItemResource>();

_logger.LogInformation(records.Count().ToString());

foreach(var record in records)
{
    _logger.LogInformation(record.ToString());
}
```

This is the content of the file

```
Msisdn, Amount, PersonName, Message, Description, Notify
69947943,150,Name 1,TEST,Test,1
69947943,150,Name 2,TEST,Test,1
69947943,150,Name 3,TEST,Test,1
69947943,150,Name 4,TEST,Test,1
69947943,150,Name 4,TEST,Test,1
69947943,150,Name 5,TEST,Test,1
```

As you can see for the sake of the test, I harcoded the path. This is the error I'm getting

> CsvHelper.HeaderValidationException: Header with name 'Msisdn' was not
>   found. If you are expecting some headers to be missing and want to
>   ignore this validation, set the configuration HeaderValidated to null.
>   You can also change the functionality to do something else, like
>   logging the issue.    at
>   CsvHelper.Configuration.ConfigurationFunctions.HeaderValidated(Boolean
>   isValid, String[] headerNames, Int32 headerNameIndex, ReadingContext
>   context)    at CsvHelper.CsvReader.ValidateHeader(ClassMap map)    at
>   CsvHelper.CsvReader.GetRecordsT+MoveNext()    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   OMBulkPayment.Controllers.PaymentsController.Payment(SavePaymentResource
>   resource) in
>   C:\Users\BMHB8456\source\repos\OMBulkPayment\OMBulkPayment\Controllers\PaymentsController.cs:line
>   59    at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object
>   target, Object[] parameters)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
>   mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
>   arguments)

Comment: It's failing on the very first field in the very first row. That sometimes indicates a larger problem, e.g. the file is actually blank, has invalid characters, or even just a blank line at the top. Check the file.

Comment: I was working on Windows 10 OS, after switched to Macos High Sierra, i get the exact error

Answer (score 2):

Nice find on using [CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/), it's an open source project and is the easiest library I've found to use.

I tried the following with your test data and was able to successfully get it working:

```
void Main()
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader("D:\\PROJECTS\\2019\\DVP_Salary_Payment_Local\\Payment\\test_2.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
    {
        csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";
        var records = csv.GetRecords<ItemResource>();
    }
}

public class ItemResource
{
    public string Msisdn { get; set; }

    public float Amount { get; set; }

    public string PersonName { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int Notify { get; set; }
}
```

You can view a nearly identical example listed on their site [here](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/get-class-records/).

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly set the delimiter. Replace the line

```
//csvReader.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";
```

with

```
csvReader.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";
```

The default delimiter depends on the system's regional settings called List separator.

Also remove spaces between header name of csv file. Keep them like below:

```
Msisdn,Amount,PersonName,Message,Description,Notify
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure about CsvHelper, but you don't really need any extra components to read CSV files natively... You can use OleDb to read it as a flat data file:

```
public DataTable ReadCsv(string filename, bool hasHeaders = true, string delimiter = ",")
{
    var dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

    var fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(filename);

    var connStr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"{0}\";Extended Properties='text;HDR={1};FMT=Delimited({2})';",
                                fi.DirectoryName,
                                ((hasHeaders) ? "Yes" : "No"),
                                delimiter);

    var commStr = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", fi.Name);

    using (var conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connStr))
    using (var cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(commStr, conn))
    using (var adapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbAdapter(cmd))
    {
        adapter.Fill(dt);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

This also has the advantage to be able to query for specific rows to return by changing the SELECT query, which you could also pass as a parameter. If you absolutely want typed data instead of strings, just create the columns manually on the datatable before calling Fill() on the adapter.